# Could condensation happen on unused heating pipe?

Tags: heating, pipe, condensation

So I used a furnace in the old days and now I switched to heating AC. But the old pipes and radiators are still in place. I just discovered that in the corner of the room the lower pipe is very cold and there is water on it and directly under it, in little pools... Could it be condensate or is the pipe leaking? Anyway, while the heating AC is good, the air obviously won't heat the floor that much, so it's around 18C, while the air in top layers is 24C. The room on the other side of the wall (where the pipe comes from) is not heated by any means as we don't use it. What can I do to the pipe to prevent it accumulating the condensation? Wrap it in a towel? :] Discharge all the water from the pipes?

Comment: If you are not using the hot water system and parts of it run through unconditioned space, you should definitely drain it (potentially to the point of blowing it clear with air) or you risk freeze damage. You may want to run a ceiling fan to help with the stratification issue (cold floor, warm ceiling.)

Answer (score 1):

Condensation happens when warm, moist air comes into contact with a cold object.  To stop the condensation you can try:

1. Removing moisture from the air
2. Wrapping the pipe in insulation
3. Removing the pipe